Flutterflow (web app) Page url not accessible (not deep linking)
I have simple page in my Flutteflow project. "[base url]/product_public" with a parameter that doesn't require auth.
I'm publishing as a web app.
However, when I run the App in test mode (also happens when deployed to a custom domain), typing the url directly in the browser:
eg. https://app.flutterflow.io/debug/pQvdjVMtOeJwaerqwr/product_public?idProduct=1
takes me to the default page. I've tried removing the param, giving the url a page name that doesn't exist, etc, but it always takes me to the default page. It's like it's ignoring the routing. I think I'm missing something very basic in the config, but everything I found in forums is about deep linking and mobile use cases.
The page itself with the param is working, because when I navigate to it through an action within the App, it works well. So it's the url routing that isn't working.
Thanks
